# Probably easy: Why is f*:A^C'->A^C continuous and cocontinuous for any functor f:C->C'?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $f:C\to C'$ be a functor, and let $A$ be a locally presentable, complete, and cocomplete category.  Then according to the paper I'm reading, the pullback functor, $f^*:A^{C'}\to A^C$ (given by precomposition with $f$), admits left and right adjoints $f_!$ and $f_*$.  It's clear that the proof of this fact follows from the adjoint functor theorem, so it suffices to show that $f^*$ is continuous and cocontinuous.

However, it's not clear to me how to show this fact.

Question:

Using the notation above, why is $f^*$ continuous and cocontinuous?

Sorry if this ends up being too easy.

Comment: I think your $f^*$ should be denoted $f_*$. Then it's left adjoint is given by a Kan extension.

Comment: I don't think that's right. f*=Hom(f,A).  It has an upper star because it is the image under a contravariant functor.  This notation is standard in descent theory as well (cf. Stacks-GIT, for instance).

Comment: I just thought about the example $f_* : Sh(X) \to Sh(Y)$ for a continunous map $f : X \to Y$.

Comment: Yeah, you flipped the variance.  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever $A$ has all small (co)limits, small (co)limits in functor categories $A^C$ are pointwise: a cone $F : I \to A^C$ is a (co)limit iff each of its “components” or “partial evaluations” $F(c) : I \to A$ is a (co)limit.

But the property of being a *pointwise* (co)limit is obviously preserved by composition with $f:C' \to C$.  So $f^*$ is continuous and co-continuous (and you can apply the AFT).

On the other hand, as Martin says in comments, we don't really need the AFT: the adjoints are given by left and right Kan extensions, which we can write down explicitly as (co)limits, as described by Michael Warren in [this recent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32791/how-is-the-right-adjoint-f-to-the-inverse-image-functor-f-described-for-f/32808#32808).

All of this is discussed in the chapters on limits and Kan extensions in Mac Lane *Categories for the working Mathematician*.  Also: we don't need the local presentability for any of this, and the limits and colimits halves each work independently of the other.